# How to fix infinite while loop and create functions

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I am trying to make a paycheck program, that utilizes functions and while loops.
In this program, I have to create two functions, one for validating the pay rate and hours, and then one for the calculations. 
In addition, I have to have the first function pass the hours and pay rate to the calculation function, and then pass it back to the first function. When I try to run the program with the first function, it seems that if I enter a pay amount under 7.25, it enters an infinite loop.

Here is the code

```
     <script>
    function payValidate(x)
    {
        if(isNaN(payRate) || payRate < 7.25 || payRate > 20)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function hoursValidate(x)
    {
        if(isNaN(hours) || hours < 1 || hours > 60)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

}
```

```
    var grossPay;
    var withHolding;
    var netPay;
    var message;



var payRate = parseInt(prompt("Enter pay rate"));

var payRateOK = payValidate(payRate);
    while(!payRateOK)
    {
        payRate = parseInt(prompt("Invalid pay rate. Enter pay rate again"));
        payRateOk = payValidate(payRate);
    }
var hours = parseFloat(prompt("Enter hours worked"));
var hoursOK = hoursValidate(hours);

while(!hoursOK)
{
    hours = parseFloat(prompt("Invalid hours. Enter hours again"));
    hoursOK = hoursValidate(hours);
}
```

```
grossPay = payRate * hours;

    if(grossPay <= 300)
    {
        withHolding = grossPay * 0.10;
    }
    else
    {
        withHolding = grossPay * 0.12;
    }
    netPay = grossPay - withHolding;


    var message = "Pay Rate: $" + payRate.toFixed(2) +
    "\nHours Worked: " + hours +
    "\nGross Pay $" + grossPay.toFixed(2) +
    "\nWithholding $" + withHolding.toFixed(2) +
    "\nNet Pay $" + netPay.toFixed(2);

    alert(message);
</script>
```

Comment: Since you have floats inside `payValidate()`, you should replace `parseInt()` with `parseFloat()`. Also use "use strict" and you will find your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var payRateOK = payValidate(payRate); // In here you have used "payRateOK"
while(!payRateOK)
{
   payRate = parseInt(prompt("Invalid pay rate. Enter pay rate again"));
   payRateOk = payValidate(payRate); // In here you have used "payRateok"
}
```

- `payRateOK != payRateOk` there for you have to use same name for that
- other thing is `payRate` is a float variable. you should use `var payRate = parseFloat` instead of `var payRate = parseInt`.
- you have used hours as `int` type there for `var hours = parseFloat` should be `var hours = parseInt`

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new variable `payRateOk` (notice the lower case k) instead of writing to `payRateOK`, the variable you check in the while loop. So payRateOK will never change, and the loop will execute infinitely.